# How can I convert a PNG to a vectorized image?

Tags: graphics, png, vector-graphics

This is the best I've found so far: http://www.tlhiv.org/rast2vec/

It works otherwise ok except that it does not support PNG transparency (it's simply gone in the resulting vector).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org).

It can vectorize bitmap (look for the proper function in "Path" menu) and exports result to .eps or .pdf file. It handles transparency as well.

Answer (score 2):

Several ways I know of:

- [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) can do it, as answered by @Wacek (good job!) (it uses [potrace](http://inkscape.org/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html) (below))
- [This website](http://www.roitsystems.com/cgi-bin/autotrace/tracer.pl) does it, pretty decent, free, been using it for a while until I learned other ways.
- Linux has a package **[autotrace](http://autotrace.sourceforge.net)**, which is customizable and controllable.  Works well.
- Linux has another package **[potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net)** which works nicely.